# Open source OMR software

Tags: windows, open-source

Is there any open source OMR (optical mark recognition) software for making and analyzing templates?

Requirements:

- Generates and reads exam sheets like in schools
- Is open source
- Does not require special hardware aside from a generic printer/scanner
- Works on Windows

Comment: There are [quite a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition#Open_source). Which format do you need?

Comment: Like on tests in schools

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question with the requirements you mentioned in the title and comments, for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [TCExam](http://www.tcexam.org/)

TCExam is a computer-based assessment system. It also has [paper testing with optical mark recognition](http://www.tcexam.org/features.php#omr)

- It generates and analyzes OMR exam templates in PDF format
- It runs on Windows (actually it's platform-independent)
- It's open-source for personal use

Comment: I must have only printer with scanner or other hardware?

Comment: @user8804 It is in PDF, so it should work with a normal printer and scanner as long as they produce a good enough quality